# Back pressed or finish() goes to the wrong task in Android

Tags: android

From a Service, I launch an Activity in my application. This is not the main application activity, just some random other activity. 
After the user has interacted with this Activity, I want to close it and return the user to where he was. So say for example he was in Facebook. My Activity gets launched. When he is done interacting with it, I want to return the user to Facebook. However, when I call finish() or backPressed() or anything like that, the Main (launcher) Activity of my application is started. I don't understand why.

Comment: Please show AndroidManifest of your app and how do you start this activity.

Comment: Ah ok, this solution did it for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38326862/882168